# Skipping gradle subtask in a subproject

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have a project rootProject and there are 5 subproject within it, which re all gradle projects. When I run gradle build from rootProject it will go and run gradle build on all subprojects. As we know gradle build task will have multiple subtasks in it like clean,compile,test.

I have a requirement that if I run gradle build from rootProject, it will go run this command on all subproject except subproject5. On subproject5, it should skip  only test subtask of build task. On the same time if I go into subproject5 directory and try to access subtask by gradle test command, it should work.

Please help me with this.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line

Comment: I can't use this command, as it will skip test on all subprojects. the command has to be gradle build. I need to put some condition in build.gradle.

Comment: You use this command by passing **the** task you want to exclude: `:subproject5:test`. If the `build` task, without any option  passed, shouldn't execute something, then that something shouldn't be done inside the standard `test` task, but inside another task, that build doesn't depend on.

Comment: I can't change the build command as it is used by multiple people. I was thinking to put some condition in build.gradle of rootProject, so that while running gradle build from rootProject, it should pickup and it will not have any effect of build.gradle of subproject5.

Comment: You shouldn't break well-established, standard conventions. build depends on test. That's a standard convention. So, again, if you want something to not be executed when executing the build task, then put that thing in a task other than the test task.

Comment: yes, I proposed the same thing , moving all tests to a different task but because of certain pipeline limitations, we can't do that

Answer (score 1):

In order to control running of test task for a certain project make a check against a passed parameter and use that parameter to remove test task. The below can be used in `build.gradle` file.

```
subprojects {
  // Add all other common stuff
  // and as last statement perform the check
  if(project.hasProperty('disableTestForProject5')) {
    project(':project5').tasks.remove(test)
  }
}
```

Now you if you want to disable test for project5 you can run build as `./gradlew build -PdisableTestForProject5`. If you do not pass the parameter the test will be executed.

To stop the test from executing permanently just remove the condition and put `project(':project5').tasks.remove(test)` as last line in `subprojects` block.